# Flutter, Intercept touch events in nested widget (Map inside PageView case)

Tags: android, flutter, gesture, touch-event

My `FlutterMap` (`flutter_map`), that responds to scale / pan / tap gestures 
 is the last element of a `CustomScrollView`, that is itself one of the pages of a `PageView`.

TL/DR: I want the map to always get the events.

[image]

As you see in the picture, Left-right touch events are consumed by `PageView` to scroll the pages. Up-Down events are consumed by `CustomScrollView` to scroll the slivers. So the map normally does not receive any events, or at random, some events ⚔️ [win that arena battle](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gesture-disambiguation) and let the user interact with the map.

```
 ❙ ★ Opening new gesture arena.
 ❙ Adding: TapGestureRecognizer#df66a(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, button: 1)
 ❙ Adding: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#2b952(start behavior: start)
 ❙ Adding: HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer#dbeae(start behavior: start)
 ❙ Closing with 3 members.
 ❙ Rejecting: TapGestureRecognizer#df66a(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: possible, button: 1)
 ❙ Accepting: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#2b952(start behavior: start)
 ❙ Self-declared winner: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#2b952(start behavior: start)
```

The self-declared winners are nearly always the `VerticalDrag` of the `CustomScrollView` or the `HorizontalDrag` of the `PageView`.

So to solve it, I have read about `RawGestureDetector` but I don´t know where to implement it or how: At root level, inside the map (not ideal as is a package), as parent of the map ... I have tried the latter, a RawGestureDetector that blocks `HorizontalDrag` and it does block it, but by winning in the arena and preventing the child map from using that event for its PositionedTapDetector inside.

So to simplify, if what I want is that the map always wins, period, what is the best practice for that? on Android I´d just override `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the map `View`.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Did you try with an `EagerGestureRecognizer`?
It's supposed to win every arena.

Comment: hi! i have moved on from flutter long ago ! sorry I can´t remember